# Set into a variable a specific line from a file in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

I'm trying to get a line from a file in Windows batch with no success. I've tried several ways to do it with I'm not an expert and it's impossible to me. The number line to read is calculated dinamically:

```
set "file=C:\myfile.txt"

REM Looking for line number where the segment "<segment>" is.
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /n "<segment>" %file%') do ( 
    set begin_line=%%L
)

echo %begin_line%
```

So I'm trying to read the line %begin_line%+1 and store it into a var.
I'm sure that the way to achieve this is with **for /f skip=%begin_line** but I couldn't do it.

Any idea?

I hope what I have requested is possible.

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question. You are searching for the first line which contains the substring **segment**. Then you want to store the *next* line inside a variable. Is that correct? If yes, here is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET inputFile=C:\myfile.txt
SET fount=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN (%inputFile%) DO (
    IF !found!==1 (
        SET foundLine=%%F
        GOTO BREAK
    )
    SET line=%%F
    SET line=!line:^<segment^>=!
    IF NOT !line!==%%F SET found=1
)
:BREAK
ECHO !foundLine!
PAUSE
```